# Google Analytics causing A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Sometimes a page is being called with a bunch of Google Analytic parameters on the end of the URL which I don't care about causing the error:
*A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)*

For example:

http://whatever.com/My-Page&ct=ga&cd=kMWRlYTU2NDVmNjA1N2E6Y28udWs6ZW46R0I&usg=GQgPDS38V0h26N-I_b59V49

I am only interested in http://whatever.com/My-Page and don't care what comes after the &

What can I do to ignore everything after the &

Comment: The issue here is that it's not appending a question mark to begin the query string. I'd double-check your settings in Adwords/Analytics/wherever, to see what might be wrong there. It seems to be behaving as if you already have a query string, so it's just appending to that, but you don't.

Comment: Thank you Matthew.  I've gone to Google Analytics / Admin / "Exclude URL Query Parameters" and added the values "ct, cd, usg".  Maybe that will work.  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.